# imagesc command for wide disperse data

Tags: matlab, image-scaling

I have a very wide disperse between min and max of a data. However when I try to display it using `imagesc`, ranges of small values being 'ignored' or displayed as '0'. Is there anyway to reasonably display the values? I tried logscale but it doesn't work.

You can see the map as below:
[image]

Where the left one has wide spread data, whereas the right one is not so disperse. Both is comparable to each other, that means the left one should have same(visually acceptable) image the right one(but it doesn't obviously).

You can obtain the data here: [LEFT](https://mega.nz/#!flcyxajD!sWEXWX91bNoYCzGg-Pinan3u6zGj1GqBVCnKyyq_MJ8) [RIGHT](https://mega.nz/#!mltGQTaI!SZXrAcKMXrfNf7mcrFmQrn017pfp2MN7R8R_6vlh_7I)

Thanks!

Comment: it's all in the `colormap`, try adding`colormap(bone(1024).^0.5))` after the imagesc line for example. Or plot the data in the log scale if it positive `imagesc(log(data+1))`

Comment: Please do not post files on mega and link them, I suggest you try to post a minimal example here, or the data in text format. Can you show an histogram? Why did log scale not work?